# Angular loading blank screen on Chrome, no errors in console

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, browser

I have an AngularJS app that works and loads well in most browsers and versions.

However, I have noticed that some people seem to be having issues loading the page on Chrome. I use Chrome as well and have tested it on all of the most recent versions; in fact, some of the people having the issues use exactly the same version of Chrome as I have and I can't seem to replicate the issue on my computer.

Checking the console, there are absolutely no errors at all. All I see is the following, which aren't part of my normal console outputs when the site does load:
[image]

I've tried disabling the cache on these browsers that seem to be having the issue but that doesn't make any difference at all. Chrome is the only browser that this happens in as well.

Checking the network tab, it looks like all of the components on the site are loaded with a HTTP 200 status as well so it doesn't look like anything is failing to load.

Looking in the source code, it looks like all the scripts are loading fine. I have a `ui-view` and and `ng-include` in my app that render the rest of the app. Looks like those aren't being rendered at all as they show up empty (ONLY in specific people's Chrome browsers):

```
<div ui-view autoscroll="false"></div>


<ng-include src="'components/loginAndSignupModal/loginAndSignupModal.html'">  </ng-include>
<ng-include src="'components/intercom/intercomChatBox.html'"></ng-include>
```

Tried changing CORS headers to `*` and that didn't work. Both the `ui-view` and the `ng-include` divs end up not rendering (only the Angular generated comments show up that indicate that the directives are there.)

Anyone have any ideas what could be happening?

Comment: I feel there is a possibility that those users might have some chrome extensions installed which might be blocking your HTML from being displayed

Comment: I thought that as well but even when running in incognito mode, the same thing happens

Comment: Well i have always had luck catching such issues when i run such applications in internet explorer keeping the debugger "ON" try it i have resolved many issues like this i go for IE8! just try u might get something :)

Comment: Debug the loginAndSignupModal- intercomChatBox-Controller. I think there is an error in the controller.

Comment: There is a lit of various manipulation proposed there : http://boardreader.com/thread/Chrome_not_loading_any_google_pages_Goog_8klxho__cs3RV2v2Oyg.html can you try them ?

Comment: Make sure it's not something as trivial as directory names with capital letters on one computer and lower case on another (we have these problem due to workspaces on Windows and Git on Linux).

Comment: @eitanfar did a  check to see if directory names were different and actually tested changing capitalizations to see if it would break in other browsers, and it did.

Comment: @mkey errors in the controller usually result in an error in the console, right? Also, why would the error only be occurring in a limited number of Chrome browsers only if it was an error in the console?

Comment: Is alerts.js your code? do you have a console.log() or $log.debug() with that `onmessage` string and an object?

Comment: Hi Karim! Did you check the extensions of the browsers where your app doesn't work? Maybe just a simple JavaScript-Blocker or something more sophisticated that tries to protect the user from 'evil' software? (i would just deactivate them all and test again)

Comment: @nabinca yes, I ran it in incognito mode which disables the extensions so that wasn't the issue

Comment: @ndaniel no alerts.js is not my code. All my code (including vendor packages from my bower components) gets compiled into scripts.js and vendor.js so if an error in my code happens there, that's where it shows up

Comment: @ndaniel no, I don't have any console.logs in my entire code base...that message doesn't actually show up when the page renders

Answer (score 1):

Hi Karim I had same issue once upon time but solve when changed to angularjs version  from 1.3 to 1.5.x   unfortunately x i can't remember but please check and let me know your both version of chrome and angular please.

Comment: Chrome version is Version 51.0.2704.84 (64-bit) and Angular version is Angular 1.4.6

Answer (score 1):

you are using ui-router to setup the view routes, do you have it properly setup in your angular app javascript?

```
<div ui-view autoscroll="false"></div>
```

the view will need to be populated for anything to appear on the screen, example:

here is a plunker example: http://plnkr.co/edit/u18KQc?p=preview

(source https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)

Comment: Yes, it works on every other browser and also works in Chrome as well of the most part. Only a few users seem to be having the problem above. So, the routes are populating properly - seems to be some weird issue where in some very limited cases, both the ui-view and ng-includes aren't populating.